# Javascript onkeyup mysql query php session kill

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, session, onkeyup

I was messing around with onkeyup events that trigger a mysql query on each keyup and found that without a delay in the JS the current PHP session will be terminated.

Because the form is behind a login and defined session ID to reach the form again would require logging in again.

I am not sure what causes this. Is this a php setting, mysql setting or is it a php session variable?

It seems to be a security feature, I would just like to know specifically where it is defined.

> Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) - MySQL client version: 5.5.38 - PHP Version
>   5.4.4-14+deb7u14

Comment: Are you able to connect to mysql first time? Then in second time session is expire?

Comment: The session only dies with multiple fast keystrokes 15 or so within a few seconds span. If keystrokes are less than 15 within a few seconds or more than 15 but entered slower the php session remains.

Comment: And yes the queries are successful.

Comment: You likely want to add some throttling (or debouncing) so that you are not hammering your server.  If you add a delay of 200-250ms after the last keystroke to run the query you'll send less queries to the server... And return a single more useful result set.

Comment: Definitely scunliffe, just curious the cause.